# Can't loop through laravel collection array

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

stuck on collection array

I am getting the specfic array. but can't loop throught in blade

this is my controller:

```
public function appliedJob($id)
{

   $apllied = AplliedJob::with('user','job')->find($id);


    return view('dashboardviews.page.apllied-job',compact('apllied'));
 }
```

this my model:

```
   class AplliedJob extends Model
   {

   use Notifiable;
   protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'message','aplied_cv',
   ];
   protected  $table='appllied_jobs';
   //protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

   protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

   public function user()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
   }
   public function job()
   {

   return $this->belongsTo('App\Job','job_id');
   }

   }
```

this the array I am getting I want to access relation# [job] but it 
       throws an error

```
   AplliedJob {#257 ▼
   #fillable: array:4 [▶]
   #table: "appllied_jobs"
   #primaryKey: "user_id"
   #connection: "mysql"
   #keyType: "int"
   +incrementing: true
   #with: []
   #withCount: []
   #perPage: 15
   +exists: true
   +wasRecentlyCreated: false
   #attributes: array:9 [▶]
   #original: array:9 [▶]
   #changes: []
   #casts: []
   #dates: []
   #dateFormat: null
   #appends: []
   #dispatchesEvents: []
   #observables: []
   #relations: array:2 [▼
   "user" => User {#263 ▼
   #fillable: array:4 [▶]
   #table: "users"
   #hidden: array:2 [▶]
   #casts: array:1 [▶]
   #connection: "mysql"
   #primaryKey: "id"
   #keyType: "int"
   +incrementing: true
   #with: []
   #withCount: []
   #perPage: 15
   +exists: true
   +wasRecentlyCreated: false
   #attributes: array:9 [▶]
   #original: array:9 [▶]
   #changes: []
   #dates: []
   #dateFormat: null
   #appends: []
   #dispatchesEvents: []
   #observables: []
   #relations: []
   #touches: []
   +timestamps: true
   #visible: []
   #guarded: array:1 [▶]
   #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
   }
   "job" => Job {#261 ▼
   #fillable: array:4 [▶]
   #table: "jobs"
   #connection: "mysql"
   #primaryKey: "id"
   #keyType: "int"
   +incrementing: true
   #with: []
   #withCount: []
   #perPage: 15
   +exists: true
   +wasRecentlyCreated: false
   #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "user_id" => 2
    "jb_name" => "web developer"
    "jb_type" => "software"
    "jb_salary" => "12000"
    "jb_exp" => "12"
    "jb_description" => "djghnbjkguyfgykgvkvbuykgbkub g uiygjghpiu p;"
    "jb_loc" => "lahore"
    "created_at" => "2019-05-15 01:18:46"
    "updated_at" => "2019-05-15 01:18:46"
     ]
     #original: array:10 [▶]
     #changes: []
     #casts: []
     #dates: []
     #dateFormat: null
     #appends: []
     #dispatchesEvents: []
     #observables: []
     #relations: []
     #touches: []
     +timestamps: true
     #hidden: []
     #visible: []
     #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
     ]
     #touches: []
     +timestamps: true
     #hidden: []
     #visible: []
     #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
```

i have tried this but it gives an exception

```
     @foreach($apllied as $aplil)

     {{$aplil->job->jb_name}}

     @endforeach
```

this the error I am getting and can't figure out what am I doing wrong

```
     ErrorException (E_ERROR)
     Trying to get property 'job' of non-object (View: 
    D:\xampp\htdocs\locojobs\resources\views\dashboardviews\page\apllied- 
    job.blade.php)
```

Comment: You have to review your table structure. can you paste your table structure?
Also, `belongsTo()` return one row not many. You have to take a look in **relations** in Laravel docs.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` return one model so you need to do this:

```
     {{$apllied ->job->jb_name}} //Remove the loop
```

or use `get()` instead of `find()`

Comment: get() feteches all the record in the table but i need specific job which user have applied. i have try this but it will only show one job applied

Comment: You need to add some conditions if you don't won't to get all records like ->where('job_id',5), find will always return one record based on applied id not job id

Comment: i tried this but whenever i use get() it return all records         $apllied = 
        AplliedJob::with(['user.job' => function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->find($id);}])->get();

Comment: You have multiple issues ['user.job'=>] should be ['user','job'=>], you shouldn't use find inside the subquery use ->where instead, the id is already in main model(belongsto) so no need to add sub queries, anyways I advise you to read the elequent relationship again.

Answer (score 0):

What i get from this code, each AplliedJob instance has one Job. So as @Anas Bakro says, you need the remove @foreach from your code. If you want to build different    architecture please write down your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use get() or paginate() instead of find(), because the find() returns single value.

Try the below code,

```
public function appliedJob($id)
{

   $apllied = AplliedJob::with('user')->with('job')->get();

    return view('dashboardviews.page.apllied-job',compact('apllied'));
}
```